# Magento can't access css files

Tags: magento, user-permissions

I updated by theme in magento 1.9 and now the frontend doesn't come up. Depending on the permissions I set, I get various errors like No Access, all pointing to a permission problem.
I ran chown -R 777 on httpdocs but the site still doesn't come up. The admin area does however load.

When I switch to Magento's rwd theme, the site does come up but it doesn't load any css (and the source shows that the code to load css and js is missing).

I am guessing that just setting permissions wasn't sufficient but that the user and group need to be set correctly. Could that be it?

If so, how do I best do that? Would chown -R user:group httpdocs do the trick and if so, what user should I use? My hosting provider recommended to not use apache:apache

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0):

Go to `configuration-> Design-> Themes` and make sure that the `skin (images/css)` field to been set correctly as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try this set permission to 755

> sudo chmod -R 755 yourfolder/

Then try ctrl+u and check the path of css files, and if you are having css files to same path.